# Implementation of Random Boolean Network in Verilog

Tags: random, boolean, verilog

I Want to implement Boolean Network in FPGA. Boolean Network Statement is given below.

A Random Boolean Network consists of N randomly connected nodes, each of which has a binary state: on or off (1 or 0). In NK networks  every node receives exactly K inputs chosen randomly from other nodes in the network and in most cases self-connection is allowed (Figure 1 shows an example of the topology of an RBN).

[image: Example of RBN]

The state of each node in the network at time t+1 is determined by the states of its inputs at time t through a randomly generated Boolean function which can be represented with a look-up table for each node (see Table 1). Typically the Boolean functions do not change throughout the lifetime of the network. In an RBN the Boolean function for each node maps each of the 2K possible input combinations to an output state of 0 or 1.

The network is given a random initial state by assigning each node a value of 0 or 1. The value of each node at the next time step is determined using the state of its inputs and each node's Boolean function. All nodes are updated at the same time (synchronously). The new state of the network is generated and then used to determine the next state and so on. An example of the network activity is displayed in Figure .

[image: Example network activity]

I really want to implement this in verilog. Can any one give me some detail about RBN?

after reading the whole statement about the Boolean Network, i can divide my problem into three steps  which are 
First i might want to implement binary network with given node function.
Second, i want to implement a random function block.
 Third - integrate the two. BTW

generate a different network every time upon reset, or in compile time

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you're trying to implement.  Are you trying to create a model of one of these networks?  Or code to produce verilog models of lots of these networks?  Are you trying to implement something in an FPGA or just a simulator?  Perhaps you want to implement some hardware in an FPGA to iterate through lots of possible permutations of these networks?

Comment: Yes, i want to implement hardware in FPGA to through lots of possible permutations of these networks. I want to implement this Boolean Network in FPGA

Comment: I think you need to edit your question and explain a bit more about your application to make it easier for people to suggest an approach to designing something.  Not the algorithm itself,  but what you're trying make.

Comment: Divide your problem. First you might want to implement binary network with **given** node function. Second, you want to implement a random function block. Third - integrate the two. BTW, Do you want it to generate a different network every time upon reset, or in compile time?

Comment: I think, if you fill FPGA's configuration memory with random data, you will get something very close to described thing : ))

Comment: @AlexeyBirukov Partially. The timing requirement won't be met, for example..

Comment: @Eugene Well, may be not completely random. For K= LUT_in one can simply disable all latch bypasses. However, it is hardly that FPGA's commutator can represent arbitrary graph, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Random boolean function `f(d_0, d_1,..,d_(k-1) )` can be represented as a `2^k` to `1` multiplexer with `2^k` random data inputs and `k` "select" inputs chosen from the `N` outputs of the other multiplexers. For timing requirements, place latches on the lines. I have drawn for you the basic block for your network:

[image: Basic RBN block]

You are going to need N blocks like this with interconnected `Q's`. You will have to implement the combination generator "N choose K", based on the input representing the choice number, and connect the top inputs to some kind of random numbers generator (compile time or not, your choice).

Comment: Thank you @Eugene SH, you are right. i want to implement this iin verilog. can you help me in understanding of the Code

Comment: It's a significant work to write code for the above. But the structural implementation given is translated 1-to-1 to the code, so I'll leave it to you, or to some one who has enough time for it.